# Run controller action with confirm form in RoR with haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Is there any possible way to run controller action with confirm form before it?

I'd like to ask user is he/she really sure to do following action. And after confirmation run this action. In other case just do nothing.

I already tried this code:

```
= form_tag( '#', onclick: "confirm('#{text}')", :controller => :payments, :action => :pay, :subscription_id => subscription_plan) do
  = hidden_field_tag 'current_subscription', subscription_plan.id
  .payment_button= image_submit_tag "/images/popup/payment/#{label_img}", :value => label.to_s, data: { disable_with: "Please wait..." }
```

And I'm interesting in is there any way to do it without JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is way

```
.payment_button= image_submit_tag "/images/popup/payment/#{label_img}", :value => label.to_s, data: { confirm: 'Your confirm message', disable_with: "Please wait..." }
```

OR another way is

```
= form_tag( '#', onsubmit => "return confirm('Are you sure?');", :controller => :payments, :action => :pay, :subscription_id => subscription_plan) do
```

Comment: Actually this also won't work without JavaScript enabled and the jQueryUjs library included. It is only an abstraction by Rails that adds this JavaScript functionality for you. So technically it is not a "non JavaScript solution".